# jQuery Popup with auto resize

Tags: jquery, popup, jquery-ui-dialog, simplemodal

I am looking for a modal popup that use you can use with an iFrame, I know there are lots.  The thing I am trying to solve for is that when the iframe does a post and if there are errors I want to auto resize the popup so there are no scroll bars.

I used used simple-modal and jQueryUI but have not been able to figure out how to do this.  I like simple-modal better because I find it easier to theme.  Can you do this with one of those plugins or is there another you can can auto resize when the page grows?

Answer (score 0):

Try using plugins provided by,

http://fancybox.net/ OR http://defunkt.io/facebox/